# memory increment of the application in the browser while running it for several hour

Tags: reactjs, memory, browser, refs, react-lifecycle

I am stuck with the memory increment of my application and as it is single page I can't even reload it. After running my application for around 5-6 hour memory size is reaching around 600mb from initial loading i.e 120mb and we did some fixed for this like making the ref to null in the componentWillunMount() and memory has reduced to 400 mb after the same testing for same time but still I can see there are lot many detached element, definitely it caused by some other parts of the code, in the snapshot file which we can take from chrome inbuilt functionality. So is there any way that I can remove all the detached-element while leaving the certain page or why don't browser removed this from memory as the detached-element is retaining some size of the memory ?

Answer (score 2):

> DOM node can only be garbage collected when there are no references to it from either the page's DOM tree or JavaScript code.

I suggest you take a look at your code and see if there are functions running not when you want it. If you use react or similar frameworks, you have to be careful with their lifecycle (important!).

Also here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/
There are many useful information, such as 
- Investigate memory allocation by function
- Spot frequent garbage collections

> So is there any way that I can remove all the detached-element while leaving the certain page or why don't browser removed this from memory

I cant offer any more accurate assumption or suggestion if what we have is `I use javascript` information. Countless consequences from countless combination of libraries, stacks and techniques make this impossible to guess.

Comment: Also it could be caused by a bug

Comment: Thanks @Nikko khresna for the information, from my side I have taken care of all this you have mentioned but definitely I am missing something. I will try to investigate more into it